# C#. Define a list of element of different generic type, but all with the same base type

Tags: c#, list, generics, covariance

I have the following structure:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public interface IFoo2 : IFoo
{
}

public interface IBar
{
}

public interface IQux<in TFoo, in TBar>
    where TFoo : IFoo
    where TBar : IBar
{
    void Normalize(TFoo a, TBar b);
}

public interface IGamma : IQux<IFoo2, IBar>
{
}

public class Gamma : IGamma
{
    public void Normalize(IFoo2 a, IBar b)
    {
        // do something with a and b
    }
}
```

I have also:

- a class that implements all the extensions of `IFoo`, that we can call `FooImpl`
- a class that implements all the extensions of `IBar`, that we can call `BarImpl`
- more extension of `IQux` where I define the type of the generics, like `IGamma`

Now, I want a list of `IQux` and call for each element the method `Normalize` with parameters an implementation of `FooImpl` and an implementation of `BarImpl`.

But if I define the list as follow and I use the method `AddQux` to add a new element to the list, I receive the following error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from `'<namespace>.IQux<TFoo, TBar>' to '<namespace>.IQux<<namespace>.IFoo, <namespace>.IBar>'` in the instruction `list.Add(c);`

```
public class Builder
{
    private IList<IQux<IFoo, IBar>> list = new List< IQux<IFoo, IBar> >();

    public void AddQux<TFoo, TBar>(IQux<TFoo, TBar> qux)
        where TFoo : IFoo
        where TBar : IBar
    {
        list.Add(qux);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how it can be solved?

Comment: Unrelated tip: avoid using `IList<T>`. It's a pain to deal with (as it doesn't implement `IReadOnlyList<T>`). Given that `Builder.list` will always be `List<T>` why not use that as its field-type? Also, `IList<T>` is invariant over `T` (unlike `IReadOnlyList<T>` which is covariant), so that's probably part of your problem.

Comment: Hint: `IQux<TFoo, TBar>` is not equivalent to `IQux<IFoo, IBar>`, even when `TFoo : IFoo` and `TBar : IBar`.

Comment: The quick-fix is to change your `AddQux` method to be non-generic (so it accepts `IQux<IFoo,IBar>`). The method you posted does not benefit from generics so using interfaces (rather than generics) should work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Your quick-fix works only in part. When I call `AddQux(new Gamma())` I receive the error `CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from '<namespace>.Gamma' to '<namespace>.IQux<<namespace>.IFoo, <namespace>.IBar>'`